# Using multiple skin in DotNetNuke

Tags: dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-7

I have a portal with BackEnd and FrontEnd sides.
I use skin A for BackEnd, skin B for FrontEnd.
I create a page P1 on FrontEnd and then drag a module with two controls:

- Control ListItem: Key = black, to show all item
- Control Detail: Key = "Display", to show item in detail

When P1 is shown up, the skin B is loaded correctly (Skin of FrontEnd). But when i click on an item, the skin A is loaded (Skin of BackEnd). I don't know why and how to solve this problem.

This is link of all Item: http://dnndev.me/vi-VN/dich-vu/cateid/104

This is link of one item: http://dnndev.me/vi-vn/dich-vu/ctl/Display/mid/544/id/88

Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 1):

With DNN, when you load a secondary control the site moves into "Isolation Mode".  This isolation mode uses the "Edit Skin" as defined in the site settings, rather than the actual skin that is created.  (It also removes all other modules from the page.)

To combat this, you might need to handle control switching on your own.  (Without using the ctl or mid parameters that trigger Isolation Mode.

Comment: Mitchells's correct about the isolation mode. The other option is to set both your main skin and you admin/edit skin to the main skin. Then, if you need the items under your Admin menu to use the admin skin, you can set the Admin menu item to use the other skin and then click the link to Propagate that skin to sub-items.

Comment: Sory Mitchel Sellers. I do not understand your guide completely. May i switch the control by hard coding instead of use Module Definition?

Comment: If you use DNN's EditUrl() routine, it will trigger the isolation mode as I mentioned.  You can look at doing some custom stuff yourself, or as a partial workaround EfficonDave's comment is also correct.  I think I have a blog post about Isolation Mode stuff, but I cannot find it at the moment.  I'll see if I can dig something up.